# Android PrintedPDFDocument without activity context?

Tags: java, android, pdf

I'm building an app that among other things generate pdfs from user data but I have a problem. To simplify it: the process seems to need an activity context but where I have my pdf generation code I can't access that.

The pdf is supposed to be auto generated on specific dates which leads to the following code (simplified):

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

`public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
     PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context,
             printAttributes);

     Page page = document.startPage(0);

     TextView TextView = new TextView(context);
     // add text and such to textview
     textview.draw(page.getCanvas());

     document.finishPage(page);

     document.writeTo(getOutputStream());

     document.close();
}`

The code above just produces an empty pdf-document. I've tried with both the context that is passed to onReceive and with context.getApplicationContext() with identical results.

However if I put the code in an activity and use "this" as the context it works. And if I, in the activity, use this.getApplicationContext() the result is again an empty pdf-document.

I realise the problem here is that it will only work with an activity context so my question to you is:

Is there a way to make the code work with an application context and if not, is there a good way to get an activity context available in my BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: "Is there a way to make the code work with an application context" -- I doubt it. Create your PDF some other way (e.g., iText or other PDF libraries, generate it on a server). "is there a good way to get an activity context available in my BroadcastReceiver" -- you can start an activity and have the activity generate the PDF. This will interfere with the user, though, if the user is using the device at the time.